# Jquery stop function when keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am newbie with Jquery , i have this function :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('*').keypress(function(e) 
    {   
        if(e.keyCode == 13) 
        { 
            $("[id^='td_']").click(function()
            {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return false ;
        }
    }); 
});
```

If enter is pressed, i can click in some text to hide him. 
The problem is that my function continue to run event if enter is not pressed.
return false do nothing .

Comment: This is just plain wrong. You can't bind the click event handler inside the keypress event handler when the enter key is pressed? It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but setting a flag when the enter key is hit, and checking for that flag inside the click event handler comes to mind, depending on what you're actually doing here ?

Comment: Every time you press the enter key you are creating a new click event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `event.preventDefault();` to avoid this behavior

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('*').keypress(function(e) 
    {   
        if(e.keyCode == 13) 
        { 
            e.preventDefault();// this will block further keypress events
            $("[id^='td_']").click(function()
            {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return false ;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: dont work, i can continue to hide event if enter is not pressed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to press enter, then be able to click to do the hide, and then the click shouldn't run again until enter is pressed first. If that's the case, you can use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$("[id^='td_']").one(function()
{
    $(this).hide();
});
```

`.one()` will only allow the handler to be called once, then it will be removed.

Comment: dont work, i can continue to hide event if enter is not pressed